# How to place text to the left of the background image and adapt it to phones

Tags: html, css

I need the text to be
text-align:center , but as soon as I write it, the text moves to the center, and I need it to be on the left and I need to adapt it to phone screens.

I tried via @media but nothing worked.
my css code

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: calc(50% - 2rem);
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding-left: 12px;
margin-top: 0;
z-index: 2;
background: none;
border-radius: .25rem;
width: 100%;
order: 2;
color: white;
```

```
bg-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img/ob.jpg"); 
  
    /* Full height */
    height: 90%;

    /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    
  
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: unset;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

my html code

```
<section class="bg-text">
<h1>ffff</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: clarification: I need text that will be located on the background, and will be on the left, but will be with text-align:center

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image overlay method inside of the picture with text.

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

```css
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Bottom left text */
.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

/* Top left text */
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

/* Top right text */
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[image]

OR

Simply you can use the CSS `shape-outside` Property to wrap the text with an image.
The `shape-outside` Property comes with values,

```
shape-outside: none |<shape-box&gt>  | <basic-shape> | <image> | initial | inherit
```